# Reducer in immutable fashion causing Uncaught Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm doing something severly wrong when trying to set state. I only have a single key-value pair `{view: ''}` as application state for the moment. Trying to set 'sections' as a value results in that word split up by each letter (copied from the redux chrome extension):

```
{view: {'0': 's','1': 'e','2': 'c','3': 't','4': 'i','5': 'o','6': 'n','7': 's', view: 'sections'}
```

And the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, view}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

The current reducer in use:

```
export default function reducer(state={}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_VIEW": {
      return {...state, view: action.payload}
    }
  }
  return state
}
```

The following reducer works, but I want to be able to set state as above where I can specify key/keys:

```
export default function view(state={}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VIEW':
      return action.payload
    default:
    return state
  }
}
```

Is this code enough to understand where things are going wrong? I'm happy to share more code if necessary. And sorry for not having a better title, but I don't know what the subject of the issue is.

**Update**

Initial state for application:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, {view: 'sections'})
```

Component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {setView} from '../actions/viewActions';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={() => this.props.setView('settings')}>SETTINGS</div>
        <div onClick={() => this.props.setView('sections')}>SECTIONS</div>
        {this.props.view}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  view: state.view
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setView: (value) => {
        dispatch(setView(value));
    }
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

The action in the file `viewActions.js`:

```
export const setView = (view) => ({
  type: 'SET_VIEW',
  payload: view
})
```

Comment: your reducer looks fine, the problem is probably in what you're dispatching. looks like you're merging the previous state with `action.payload`

Comment: Could you also add the initial state structure and the action where you form the payload?

Comment: @dhilt initial state is an empty object `state={}` (default argument)

Comment: Question updated with component code and initial application state structure.

Comment: can you show this function `setView`

Comment: @FellowStranger The code looks fine, the only place that is still unclear is the action creator...

Comment: Updated with the action.

Comment: somewhere in your code you must be doing something like `...state.view` or `...action.payload`

Comment: The crazy thing is that I don't. I have very few files, the code is pretty much what I've posted. This thing that state gets updated with the word "sections" split up to letters - how can that happen?

Comment: that's the result of spreading a string into an object. you can test in chrome console `var a = 'foo'; var b = {...a}`

Answer (score 0):

Still have no idea why your code doesn't work. I created simple [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/k00z457v4r) which repeats your code and which is working fine. Hope, it will be helpfull.

Comment: hmm swapping out your reducer with his original reducer doesn't change anything https://codesandbox.io/s/0p322474on

Comment: @azium You right, i missed `return`. By the way, now he'll be able to compare his codebase with working demo...

Comment: Thank you so much for writing the demo. It's so frustrating that I don't find where the problem is, but perhaps by comparing with your code I'll understand it.

Comment: @FellowStranger I updated the demo (removed extra code). Looks like it's an infrastructure issue... don't forget to tell us what was wrong when it will be fixed